# Select changes on days

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make report based on user table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
 `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `register_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And I need to show how many users registered in a interval of time. I try this

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) as "user_count" FROM user u WHERE u.register_date > '2016-01-01' AND u.register_date < '2016-10-24';
```

There is a way to make it by day?. i.e. I have initDate and endDate and I get how many users register every day between this days. e.g.

day = 2016-10-23

user_count = 2

---

day = 2016-10-24

user_count = 5

---

day = 2016-10-25

user_count = 0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DATE()` function to extract the DATEs from your datetime column, then `GROUP BY` those dates:

```
SELECT DATE(u.register_date),COUNT(u.id) as "user_count" 
FROM user u
WHERE u.register_date > '2016-01-01' 
AND u.register_date < '2016-10-24'
GROUP BY DATE(u.register_date)
ORDER BY DATE(u.register_date);
```

Comment: But there is a way to get the missing days setting user_count in 0?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DATE()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm#function_date) function the get the date from the `register_date` column, and group by it:

```
SELECT DATE(register_date) as registeringDay ,COUNT(u.id) as "user_count" FROM
    user WHERE u.register_date > '2016-01-01' AND u.register_date < '2016-10-24' 
    GROUP BY registringDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the date to the query and GROUP by the date

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count`, `register_date`
FROM `user`
WHERE `register_date` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-10-24'
GROUP BY `register_date`;
```

If the `register_date` is a DATETIME column

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count`, DATE(`register_date`) as `day`
FROM `user`
WHERE `register_date` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-10-24'
GROUP BY DATE(`register_date`);
```